# MDX Statement Returning Nothing

Tags: ssas, olap, olap-cube

I have a Dimension called `ExDimension` with 1 single attribute called `ExAttribute`. I currently have 2 members in that dimension along with the `unknownmember` with data for it. When I run the following MDX, I get nothing back and I don't understand why. Can anyone give me a direction on where to look?

```
SELECT 
{
    [ExDimension].[ExAttribute].CHILDREN
} 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES [ExDimension].[ExAttribute].[Attribute Code], 
                     [ExDimension].[ExAttribute].[Company], 
                     [ExDimension].[ExAttribute].[Is Current], 
                     [ExDimension].[ExAttribute].[Is Current Store], 
                     [ExDimension].[ExAttribute].[Is Current Chain], 
                     [ExDimension].[ExAttribute].[Attribute Label] 
ON 0 FROM [CR Data Warehouse]
```

Comment: What do you get when you replace `[ExDimension].[ExAttribute].CHILDREN` with `[ExDimension].[ExAttribute].Members`? Are you sure you have no type in the dimension and attribute name? The default setting of Analysis Services is not to show errors if attributes are referenced which do not exist, but just silently ignore them.

Comment: I get the right values... everything looks good. This is what I'm not understanding because this query structure will work for all my other Dimensions/Attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code relies on an implicit type conversion of Analysis Services:

`Children` works on a member, see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146018.aspx). And you give it a  hierarchy. In this case, SSAS does an implicit type conversion to the default member of the hierarchy. I. e. the code

```
[ExDimension].[ExAttribute].CHILDREN
```

is equivalent to

```
[ExDimension].[ExAttribute].DefaultMember.CHILDREN
```

In the standard case, this works as the default member is the `All` member, which has all the "normal" members as its children. I would assume that your `ExAttribute` hierarchy has a default member which is not the `All` member, but a member on the bottom level. And that does not have children, hence the above expression returns the empty set.

Assuming your intention is to get the members of the `ExAttribute` attribute hierarchy except for the `All` member, my preferred way of coding this would be to use

```
[ExDimension].[ExAttribute].[ExAttribute].Members
```

This does not use an implicit type conversion, and uses the `ExAttribute` level of the `ExAttribute` attribute hierarchy. Attribute hierarchies normally have two levels: the `All` level consisting just of the `All` member, and the level named like the attribute, which contains all the members coming directly from the dimension table. There can be variations: If you set the attribute property `IsAggregatable` to false, the `All` member and the `All` level is missing, and you can add calculated members to both levels.

You could even use

```
[ExDimension].[ExAttribute].[ExAttribute]
```

as, again, there is an implicit type conversion if you have a level and need a set: This implicit type conversion applies the `Members` function. But I prefer to be explicit, especially as the code does not get that much longer this way.

Comment: Fantastic explanation! This is how I learn. Thank you so much!