# dynamic sorting in a mdx query based always upon last month

Tags: sorting, filter, mdx

I'm dealing with another MDX problem, this time I can't find out solution for this problem:
I need to sort some results based on last month, but I don't know which month is last in advance. It depends on the query

```
SELECT 
    {[Measures].[MQ]} ON COLUMNS, 
    ORDER(
        FILTER( 
            [dim_ProductModel].[Product Model].&[DSDC]
            *
            [dim_SpareParts].[Spare Group].children,
            ([Measures].[MQ]) > 0
            ),
        ([Dim_Date].[Date Full].&[2013-12-01],[Measures].[MQ]) , 
        desc
    ) 
    * 
    [Dim_Date].[Date Full].children
ON ROWS 
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        BOTTOMCOUNT(
            {FILTER( 
                EXCEPT(
                    [Dim_Date].[Date Full].children, 
                    {[Dim_Date].[Date Full].UNKNOWNMEMBER} 
                ),
            ([Measures].[MQ]) > 0
            )},
            7) ON COLUMNS
    FROM 
        [cub_sfr_spare_parts_groups] 
    WHERE 
        ([dim_ProductModel].[Product Model].&[DSDC])
)
```

The thing is, this would be sorted correctly only if the last month is 2013-12. Otherwise if the 2013-12 does not exist alphabetical sorting is applied.

Now, I can get the last month by using TAIL([Dim_Date].[Date Full].children,1) however, this is not allowed to use it in my order clause. He means I should provide him a string/literal expresion and not a tuple expression, although, TAIL with 1 as 2.parameter gives me only one result!

Is there some way how to convert this tuple expression to string expression?
Or any other option how to sort by last date?

If I use .lastchild this wont help me, because the lastchild is not the last nonempty month I need. (NONEMPTY(.lastchild) is not working as well)

Thank you very much for any kind of help,

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see [in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146056.aspx), `Tail` returns a set. You can use the [set to tuple version of the `Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145501.aspx) function to get a tuple form the set, and the [tuple to member version of the `Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145562.aspx) function to get a member from the tuple. This can then be used in the tuple in your filter definition.

Thus, your expression to use would be

```
Tail([Dim_Date].[Date Full].children, 1).Item(0).Item(0)
```

or, even better (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22488698/mdx-statement-returning-nothing))

```
Tail([Dim_Date].[Date Full].Members, 1).Item(0).Item(0)
```

Comment: Thank you at first for your (as usual) very well structured answer. Now the sorting is almost working correctly. It works, as long as I delete the [dim_ProductModel].[Product Model].&[DSDC] attribute right after the filter opening. Otherwise it is sorted alphabeticaly. Strange behaviour, if I use "hardcoded" date member ([Dim_Date].[Date Full].&[2013-12-01] in this case) in the sorting, it however works also with the attribute.I'm going to examinate it further. –  Peter 10 mins ago

Comment: Interesting is, that If I delete the  [dim_ProductModel].[Product Model].&[DSDC] and put it into new WHERE condition at the end of the query, the sorting is not working as well.

Comment: no..it is simply not working when I want to add a filter for product model, however it is working fine without product model filter. Is there any explanation for this behaviour? Like when I add the Product Model into WHERE or FILTER the  expression TAIL([Dim_Date].[Date Full].children,1) is evaluated after the order by is applied?

Comment: Maybe you should replace `DESC` with `BDESC` in the `Order` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145587.aspx)?

Comment: unfortunately this has not helped as well. Couldn't I somehow calculate the last month in advance, store it into a variable and then use the variable in the SORT part?

Comment: @Peter I would try to split the calculations into several steps, like putting the `Filter(...)` into a calculated set. Then you can have a look into the separate steps, and see more clearly where the result is as you expect it and where in the calculation it starts deviating from your expectation.

Comment: I think I understand where is the problem. The Date Full attribute has members from 2007-04 till 2013-12. In my "subcube" I am filtering this attribute with MQ>0 and BOTTOMCOUNT so that I get last month not 2013-12 but the one where MQ>0. So far good, if I replace [Dim_Date].[Date Full].children on line 14 with Tail([Dim_Date].[Date Full].children, 1).Item(0).Item(0) I did get last month with MQ>0 indeed. However by the time the filter is applied on line 5, the SSAS still doesn't know that Tail([Dim_Date].[Date Full].children, 1).Item(0).Item(0) is not 2013-12 and it takes  2013-12 as TAIL.

Comment: got it at last..WITH MEMBER [Dim_Date].[Date Full].[last] AS Tail(   FILTER([Dim_Date].[Date Full].members, MQ>0), 1).Item(0).Item(0), and then I used this in the order by clause..